# Criterion for function to be measurable on product space

Tags: measure-theory

I was wondering if there is some sort of go to criterion to check if a function is measurable on a product space. Consider for example the following situation. Let $f: \Omega_1 \times \Omega_2 \to \Omega_3$ be a given function. Lets say we further have that $(\Omega_1, \mathcal{A}, \mu), (\Omega_2, \mathcal{B'},\nu), (\Omega_3, \mathcal{C}, \alpha)$ be measure spaces. In order for theorems such as the theorem of Fubini-Tonelli to be applied one needs to check that $f$ is measurable on $ \mathcal{A} \otimes \mathcal{B'}$. How is that usually done? I've read that it is not true that $f$ is measurable if both $f(x,-)$ and $f(-,y)$ are measurable, so I wondered what would be the a good/simple criterion, since I don't know any. One could also consider a less general setting, such as $(\Omega_3, \mathcal{C}, \alpha)=(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}, \lambda)$ with $\mathcal{B}$ denoting the Borel-sigma-algebra and $\lambda$ being the borel-measure. Thank you in advance for any comment.

Comment: for the general setting it is enough to check that $f^{-1}(A)$ is measurable for any class of sets $\mathcal{E}$ such that $\sigma (\mathcal{E})=\mathcal{C}$

Comment: @Masacroso Thank you for your comment. As far as I understand, you use the definition of measurable here, right (in case you have a suitable generating set $\mathcal{E}$)? I just thought that this might sometimes be complicated, which is why I was looking for a simpler criterion, if there exists one.